Lazarus-Chart: How can I place a Label in a BarSeries above the bars instead of centered in the middle of the bar (default)
I would like to place a Label in a TChart-BarSeries of Lazarus above the bars.
Is there a way to place a Label above a bar of a TBarSeries instead of centered (This is the default)?
I have not found an approach yet - no Idea
